# Formulate a model that predicts the amount of oil in the gulf on day n.

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I believe I have the mathematical model correct. My main concern is part d. I am unsure of how to even approach this. Do I need to first calculate how much oil is cleaned after 25 days with my math model from part a? Then, how do I include the 100 barrels part? 
I **cannot** use formulas only discrete dynamical systems.  [image]

Comment: So do I interpret it correctly that your model is, that on the $n$:th day there is
$$
f(n) = -0.1 n + 4000
$$
barrels of oil? I don't think this is exactly correct ... The statement says "crews are able to remove about $10~\%$ of the oil in the water each day". So in the beginning, there is $4000$ barrels, on the next day there is $0.9 \times 4000$, on the day after that there's $0.9 \times 0.9 \times 4000$ ... Do you agree?

Comment: You went wrong right at the start. The oil is leaking continuously 4000 per day. The cleanup removes 10% of the **total** not so far removed. You seem to be working on the basis that the spillage is not continuing, so there is only a total of 4000 to remove.

Comment: I agree with @almagest. The model does not take into account that there is an additional spill of $4000$ barrels of oil _every day_. The current model only considers [the accuracy of which needs to be re-evaluated] _one_ oil spill and predicts the fraction of this remaining after $n$ days.